# Migrations on Entity Framework Multiple Developers Issue

Tags: entity-framework, database-migration

We are working with Code First Migrations EF 5.0.0.rc and we are having problems when two people on the team create migrations at the same time and then commit their changes.

This looks because the Update-Database compares again the latest migration model hash or something that does not have my changes because it was commited by someone else. So is based in the database state of the latest migration, and then ignoring the changes I already applied previously.

This is a very ugly behaviour when working with local databases to simplify development and remote work. I guess this should work different, always using the current model for comparison and not the latest one declared in the Migration file model hash.

Or we are doing something wrong? Anybody with this issue?
The migration tool is really awesome, but it's very difficult to work on diverse environments, remote without this feature working fine and we are struggling our head because this looks very basic feature.

Thanks,
Leonardo

Comment: Can you explain how is it *ignoring changes you have already applied*? What do you mean by *applied*?

Comment: This smells alot like the problems we are having. Inexplicable behaviour at random times.

Comment: You might want to keep an eye on http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/760 and http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/780